# xcodebuild error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, jenkins

I am getting a very weird error when trying to utilize xcodebuild. Below is the error that is being logged.

> xcodebuild clean build -configuration Release -target
>   WhiteLabelLibrary -sdk iphoneos 2012-07-05 10:27 xcodebuild[83795]
>   (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamStart: ERROR: FSEvents_connect()
>   => (ipc/send) invalid destination port (268435459) 2012-07-05 10:27 xcodebuild[83795] (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamInvalidate():
>   failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> 2012-07-05 10:27 xcodebuild[83795] (CarbonCore.framework)
>   FSEventStreamRelease(): failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> 2012-07-05 10:27:38.570 xcodebuild[83795:1603] [?T] Failed to start fs
>   event stream. xcodebuild: error: Initialization failed.   Reason:
>   Scanning for plug-ins failed.

Have anyone gone through this error? I have no clue how to fix this error.

Thanks

Comment: CarbonCore?  That's an OSX framework.

Comment: So here is what is happening. I tried building the project from terminal and it worked. However, I am trying to build from Jenkins, and that is what its throwing those error. Could be something related to the plugin?

Comment: FSEventStreamStart used to be the error that prevented OS X leopard from being installed on unauthorized PPC machines.  Maybe Jenkins has insufficient privileges.  FS stands for file-system, so...

Comment: How did you install Jenkins? Is it running as launch daemon? Under which user?

Comment: Community, I finally got it working, I just had to restart the server. Somehow it was not initializing the ports to access these sdk's properly. I have admin rights so everything seams back to normal now. Thanks for all your input.

Comment: @kforkarim You should paste this solution into an answer and accept it so that this question is marked as answered. (Otherwise it will continue to show up on the unanswered list).